# How to call touchesBegan on a layer that is a sublayer of a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer

I have a layer that I have added as a sublayer of a `UIWebView`. I would like to be able to touch and drag the layer around. Before I added the `UIWebView`, I was able to touch and drag around the layer without a problem.

Here's where I create the layer and add it as a sublayer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    starLayer = [CALayer layer];
    starLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage
                                                                      imageNamed:@"star"]].CGColor;
    starLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    starLayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    starLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    starLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    starLayer.frame = CGRectMake(235.0, 200.0, 35.0, 35.0);
    [self.aboutWebView.layer addSublayer:starLayer];

    [self moveStar];
}
```

Here's my `moveStar` method

```
- (void)moveStar
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation *move = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
    [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 50.0)]];
    [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 250.0)]];
    [move setValues:values];
    [move setDuration:1.0];
    [move setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

    // Add the animation to the layer to be animated
    [starLayer addAnimation:move forKey:@"moveAnimation"];
```

}

So far so good. The star falls onto the screen and lands a bit above the middle. But when I try and touch the star nothing happens. `touchesBegan` never gets called for some reason.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.aboutWebView];
    [starLayer setPosition:point];
}
```

Is the reason I can't touch the star when it's a sublayer of `aboutWebView` because a touch is reported to a view, not a layer?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the star as a sublayer of `aboutWebView` touchable? Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layer... try to set the `UIGestureRecognizer` property `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO.

"Setting this value to NO instructs the recognizer to deliver all touches to the underlying view, even when it has recognized the sequence"

something like that:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *touches = [UIGestureRecognizer alloc];
    //or
    //UIGestureRecognizer *touches = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchesAction:)];

    touches.enabled=YES;
    [yourLayer addGestureRecognizer:touches];
    touches.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
```

Comment: I tried your suggested code in my `viewDidLoad` and made "yourLayer" `starLayer`. I got the error "No visible @interface for `CALayer` declares the selector `addGestureRecognizer:`
Is `starLayer` not what should be put in place of "yourLayer"?

Comment: What you have in header file? Let's say: UIWebView *webview; you must write:  [self.webview addGestureRec...];

Comment: In my header file I have `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *aboutWebView;`
I added self.aboutWebView addGestureRec... along with your other suggested code and it still didn't do anything... hmmm

Comment: aaa, I see now.. you are using CALayer.. maybe that can help you http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you for all your help!